# Depth of a binary Tree in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, binary-tree

I'm trying to write code to find the depth of a binary tree.

I know that it need to be rekursiv,thank you very much in advance for your answer.

Here is my Code in Kotlin.

```
    sealed class Tree <A>{

    abstract fun isEmpty() : Boolean
    abstract fun size() : Int
    abstract fun depth() : Int

}

private data class Node <A >(
    val value : A,
    val left : Tree <A>,
    val right : Tree <A>
) : Tree <A >() {
    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean = false

    override fun size(): Int = 1 + left.size() + right.size()

    override fun depth(): Int {

         if (!left.isEmpty()) // I tried to work with isEmpty()

    }
}

private object Empty : Tree < Nothing >() {
    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean = true
    override fun size(): Int = 0
    override fun depth(): Int = 0
}

fun <A> emptyTree () : Tree <A> = Empty as Tree <A>
fun <A> treeNode (
    value : A,
    left : Tree <A> = emptyTree () ,
    right : Tree <A> = emptyTree ()
): Tree <A> = Node (value , left , right )


fun main(){

    var tree : Tree<Int> = emptyTree()

    tree = treeNode(5,treeNode(3,treeNode(2,treeNode(1)),treeNode(4)),treeNode(8,emptyTree(),treeNode(10)));
```

I tested my Code with a Tree with 7 Nodes

```
    println(tree.size())
    println(tree.depth())
}
```

Comment: Of course, there are many different ways to implement even a simple binary tree, with different performance characteristics. For example, if checking the height was going to be a very common operation, then each node could have a field with the height of its subtree — it would take a little extra memory to store that, and some extra work to maintain it, but checking the height would then be a constant-time operation. As always, it helps to understand a bit about the processing so you can pick the most appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it in the same way as size: the depth of a node is 1 plus the largest of left.depth() and right.depth().

Comment: `override fun depth(): Int = 1 + if (left.depth() >= right.depth()) left.depth() else right.depth()` is this right?

Comment: Yes, that works, but it will call the depth()-methods twice each. 1 + max(left.depth(), right.depth()) would be even better.